# Sequential parsing with jsoup

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup, html-parsing

I want to parse some html page, for example:

```
<div class="class_Name">
"Unknown text"
<img src="link_To_Image">
"Unknown text"
</div>
```

With this code

```java
Element element = document.select("div.class_Name").first();
Elements elements = element.children();
```

But elements store only nested tags, so it stores only image.
What should i do for parse in right order?

Comment: What do you want to achieve eventually? What is expected result?

Comment: @SergeyProkofiev, I want to compose content in the same order as it is located on the site. But now, I can compose it in this order: text1, text2, image or image text1, text2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your request correctly, you're looking for the way to get collection of all internal nodes of enclosing `div`. If so, you need to call [`Node.childNodes`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#childNodes--)

```
    String input = "<div class=\"class_Name\">\n\"Unknown text\"\n"
        + "<img src=\"link_To_Image\">\n\"Unknown text\"\n</div>";

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input);
    Element element = doc.select("div.class_Name").first();

    List<Node> nodes = element.childNodes();
    for (Node n : nodes) {
        System.out.println(n);
    }
```

Will print

```
 "Unknown text" 
 <img src="link_To_Image">
 "Unknown text"
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what i need.